# Logarithmic inequation $\frac{3^{x+1}}{2^{x+3}}+2\leq \frac{2^{x-1}}{3^{x-1}}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Solve inequation

$$\frac{3^{x+1}}{2^{x+3}}+2\leq \frac{2^{x-1}}{3^{x-1}}$$

I am trying to solve it, but I am stuck here...

$$\dfrac{3^{2x}-4^{2x}+\frac{16}3\times 6^x}{\frac83\times6^x}\leq 0$$

Comment: Can you show us how you got to that point? It may help us to understand what techniques you have been taught about to solve these kind of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying through by $\frac{3^{x-1}}{2^{x-1}}$ gives:
$$\frac{3^{2x}}{2^{2x+2}} + \frac{2\cdot 3^{x-1}}{2^{x-1}} \leq 1$$
or equivalently,
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2x} + \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x-1 \leq 0.$$
Let $y=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x$. We want to solve $\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{4}{3}y-1 \leq 0$. Using the quadratic formula or factoring, we find the roots of this equation are $y=-6$ and $y=\frac{2}{3}$, so $\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{4}{3}y-1 \leq 0$ whenever $y \in [-6,\frac{2}{3}]$.

So finally, we need to solve the inequalities $-6 \leq y \leq \frac{2}{3}$, i.e., $-6 \leq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x \leq \frac{2}{3}$. Since $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x >0$ for all $x$, the lower bound always holds. Thus the inequality is reduced to solving $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x \leq \frac{2}{3}$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes I can :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since everything in sight is continuous, we should first solve the corresponding equality.  Clear the fractions and put everything on one side to get

$$2^{2x+2} -2\cdot3^{x-1}2^{x+3} - 3^{2x} = 0.$$

Pull out the odd powers:

$$4\cdot 2^{2x} - 16\cdot 2^x \frac{1}{3} 3^x -3^{2x}=0.$$

Multiply by $3$ and let $a=2^x$ and $b=3^x$:

$$12a^2 - 16ab - 3b^2 = 0.$$

This factors

$$(6a-b)(2a-3b) = 0.$$

This gives two easy equations in $x$ leading to
two solutions.  From there the inequality is easy.

Answer (score 0):

First, your inequality,
$$  \frac{3^{2x}-4^{2x}+\frac{16}{3}\times 6^x}{\frac{8}{3}\times 6^x} \leq 0  \text{,}  $$
has an always positive denominator on the left-hand side, so the denominator cannot make the left-hand side zero or change its sign.  Hence, you can reduce to 
$$  3^{2x}-4^{2x}+\frac{16}{3}\times 6^x \leq 0  \text{.}  $$

However, much better is to note that in your original inequality, you very nearly have the same expressions involving exponents.  Let's see if we can make this matching exact.
$$  \frac{9}{16} \left( \frac{2^{x-1}}{3^{x-1}} \right)^{-1} + 2 \leq \frac{2^{x-1}}{3^{x-1}}  \text{.}  $$
Let $u = \frac{2^{x-1}}{3^{x-1}}$ so that the inequality is 
$$  \frac{9}{16u} + 2 \leq u  \text{,}  $$
which is much easier to solve.  You will get two intervals for $u$.  But $\frac{2^{x-1}}{3^{x-1}}$ is always positive, so we can restrict the intervals by intersecting with $(0,\infty)$ to get solutions for $u$ that correspond to valid values of $x$.